# Difference between accessing website with index.php and /

Tags: php

I have the following blocks before and after my php to cache the html generated by the php file into a html file. When I access the website with http://domain.com/index.php, it builds the html file and puts it in the directory and servers it for the subsequent request. If I access the website with just http://domain.com, the html file is not written to the directory. Is there a difference in accessing with and with out the index.php in the url? Other thing I noticed is, once the html file is built, that file is served for both index.php and /

**at the beginning of index.php:**

```
if (file_exists($cachefile)) {
    readfile($cachefile);
    echo "<!-- From Cache -->";
    exit;
}
ob_start(); /*Start the output buffer*/
?>
```

**at the end of index.php:**

```
<?php
$fp = fopen($cachefile, 'w');
fwrite($fp, ob_get_contents()); 
fclose($fp);
ob_end_flush(); /* Send the output to the browser */
?>
```

Comment: do you have index.html in your root folder ?

Comment: what filename are you using for `$cachefile`, if its index.html or index.htm, that is your problem

Comment: I don't have index.html. Also, I write to a directory other than the  root directory.  My cache file name is n9home.html